# Michael Hartl ch9 : how to sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I’ve completed Michael Hartl ch 9 and have no error in testing.
But I could not  sign up...

It returns error as below even so previously I be able to sign up..login works fine.

How to fix it and be able to sign up?

Should I  merge  sign up branch? But doing that I could loose all changes..  Could something be done about sign up form this more advance branch?

Error:

> No route matches [POST] "/signup"

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root   'static_pages#home'

  get    '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  get    '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  get    '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get    '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :users
end
```

thanks.

Thanks everybody for answers.
It works now. 
One more question related. 
When users sign up - they could directly participate in website. It is no good since they need to get confirmation by email and only that they could participate.

How it could be implemented?

I think it is in the solutions Michael Hartl and I even implemented it for Rails 4, but could not remember what need to change.. 
What files need to be changed to allow users participate in website only after getting confirmation by email.
thanks.

Comment: You have no route to `POST /signup`, what action triggered that error? You need either to setup that route or call another one.

Answer (score 0):

The error is very clear and crisp, you don't have a route for `users#create`, you need to implement that action and it should work.

Go through [this section](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up#sec-a_working_form) in the book..

Answer (score 0):

> No route matches [POST] "/signup"

You should have `post '/signup', to: 'users#create'` in your routes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
  post '/signup',  to: 'users#create'
```

And write create method in

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # Create User with signup parameterss
  end
end
```